# Local Weierstrass preparation

Tags: reference-request

I could not find a reference of the local version of Weierstrass preparation theorem It is used for example in Denef & van den Dries "$p$-adic and real subanalytic sets".
Can you help, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See '$p$-adic numbers, $p$-adic analysis, and zeta-functions' by Koblitz. Chapter IV sections 3 and 4 have a good exposition on newton polygons and the Weierstrass preparation theorem.

Comment: What I need more precisely is the statment and proof of LOCAL weierstrass preparation. I did not find that in Koblitz's book.

Answer (score -1):

A good elementary proof of the Weierstrass preparation theorem can be found in the Jun-ichi Igusa's *An introduction to the theory of Local Zeta Functions* ([Google books link](http://books.google.com.mx/books/about/An_Introduction_to_the_Theory_of_Local_Z.html?id=yPXK10jqMj8C&redir_esc=y)).

See Chapter 2, section 2.3.